# Select and rearrange DataFrame rows using a Python list and keeping data order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a large *Pandas* DataFrame made of 298k rows. One column is **ID** and it is unique for each row.
I want to perform two operations:

1. Filter the dataframe rows such that the ID value for each row is within a Python list, called *my_list* that contains 13k elements. I tried using *query()* and it works fine:

   `df= df.query(f'ID in {my_list}')`
2. Now, I want to rearrange the dataframe such that the order of the IDs is the same as the one in *my_list*, which is an ordered list that may contain duplicates. 
    If there is a duplicate in the list, I want to add the duplicate row even in the dataframe, keeping the order.

   I tried using categories to order the dataframe but it does not work with duplicates and I have no idea how to add the duplicate row if there is one in the list:

   `df['ID'] = pd.Categorical(df['ID'], categories=mylist, ordered=True)`

Any efficient solutions? Thanks

**Numerical example**: 
I have a list with these IDs: [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2].
And I have a dataframe with these rows:

| ID | Name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | John | ... |
| 1 | Paul | ... |
| 2 | Rick | ... |
| 3 | Jean | ... |
| 4 | Mark | ... |
| 5 | Neil | ... |
| 6 | Martin | ... |

I want in output this dataframe, following the list order and adding duplicates in the df:

| ID | Name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paul | ... |
| 2 | Rick | ... |
| 3 | Jean | ... |
| 1 | Paul | ... |
| 4 | Mark | ... |
| 2 | Rick | ... |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the original index is not critical, you can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df.set_index('ID').reindex(my_list).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
id_list = [43849175, 13239461, 14461786, 14467946, 14461786]

df_concat = pd.DataFrame()
for id in id_list:
    row = df[df["ID"] == id]
    df_concat = pd.concat([df_concat, row], ignore_index=True)
```

Maybe a more efficient way to do it:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({"ID": id_list})
df_result = df_result.merge(df, left_on="ID", right_on="ID", how="left")
```

Comment: you're right, check my edit, maybe it's more efficient using pd.merge

Comment: Nice solution too! However the @mozway answer is faster due to the use of indexes.